# Hide section if it's empty (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I can't understand how do not to display my section if its value is empty.

```
<div class="innerColumn">
                <?php
                $my_page_id = 142; //your page or post ID
                $my_page = get_post($my_page_id); //retrieves the page via the ID
                $content = $my_page->post_content; //gets the unfiltered page content
                $title = $my_page->post_title; //retrieves page title and sets the variable
                ?>
                <h1 class="titleHead"><?php echo $title ?></h1>
    
                    <p><?php echo $content ?></p>
                
    
       
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to hide it is to wrap the element in an if statement with an empty check

```php
if(!empty($YOUR_VARIABLE)){ //Code you want to conditionally show}
```

so in your case I would do (and assuming you want to hide the whole div based on `$content`):

```php
<?php
$my_page_id = 142; //your page or post ID
$my_page = get_post($my_page_id); //retrieves the page via the ID
$content = $my_page->post_content; //gets the unfiltered page content
$title = $my_page->post_title; //retrieves page title and sets the variable
?>

<?php if (!empty($content)): ?>
    <div class="innerColumn">
        <h1 class="titleHead"><?= $title ?></h1>
        <p><?= $content ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

(I took the liberty to clean the code a little, note the shorthand for echo `<?=?>`